# NUnit Is and Is.Not EqualTo Constraints

Tags: nunit

I would expect the following:

```
var a = Is.EqualTo("OK").ApplyTo("OK").IsSuccess;
var b = Is.Not.EqualTo("OK").ApplyTo("OK").IsSuccess;
```

To return different results, but they are both true. Could somebody explain what I am missing?

I was hoping to use NUnit's constraint checks in my own test code but external to a call to e.g. Assert.That but this behaviour is not what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to set up a test in the debugger to be absolutely sure, but at first  glance, here is what I think is happening...

NUnit uses internal stacks of operators and operands to parse the fluent syntax. Is.Not.EqualTo("OK") generates an EqualConstraint with a Not operator saved on the stack. Your ApplyTo call runs against the EqualConstraint.

I suspect that if you interjected a call to Resolve() right after the equal constraint, the result would be as you expect.

```
var b = Is.Not.EqualTo("OK").Resolve().ApplyTo("OK").IsSuccess;
```

The fact is that the constraint operators are syntactic sugar intended for direct use in tests and not for more general use.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, and you were right that .Resolve() 'fixes' it.